# Java - Iterate through a ResultSet till find the correct file

Tags: java, iteration, resultset

I have files with data (file1_01032021, file2_02032021) and corresponding information files (info1_01032020, info2_02032020).
file1 belongs to info1 and file2 belongs to info2. They arrive in hdfs and the filenames are logged in a database when a file arrived. In the information file, the name to the data file is pointed.
So info1 has content for example:

```
"blabla" : "blabla"
"dataFile" : "info1_01032020"
```

I have created a variable r which is a ResultSet of the data from this table where the type of the file is information.
The table looks like:

```
date      | filePath | type
01032020  | info1    | information
02032020  | info2    | information
01032021  | file1    | data
02032021  | file2    | data
```

In the ResultSet (r) the following rows are stored:

```
01032020  | info1    | information
02032020  | info2    | information
```

For me the column "filePath" is interesting. I have to find the corresponding information filename for each data file.
I need some kind of Iterator through this ResultSet and look into the file and see to which file with data belongs. I have the following code:

```
if (r.next())    
informationFile = r.getString("filePath");
```

but it takes only the last loaded file and does not check to which data file it belongs.

Can anyone help me with the iteration with some example code?

Comment: You need some kind of loop. Instead of `if(r.next())`, you need to loop through the results using something like `while(r.next())`, where you do work on each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: On a side note, I'd recommend storing the information from the information file into columns in your database. Iteration over rows that point to files that need to be loaded and parsed is pretty resource expensive. Other than that, @Brendan Lesniak is right about the while loop :)

Comment: @RandomCoder_01, didn't even catch that on initial read. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this like that :

```
while (r.next())   { 
  informationFile = r.getString("filePath");
  String file = "file"+informationFile.substring(4);
  readFile(file); // You need to create this method
}
```